# How can I get the value of the change scroll y-axis in android ListView?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

[Link](http://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling%28part1%29/)

If you look at the link above, you can inherit the scrollListener of recyclerView

Check the amount of change in the y-axis when it is scrolled, it is processing a variety of events.

Using the expanderableListView, it tries to process the same event,

It does not be able to retrieve the scroll in the y-axis direction at all value.

Alternatively, when other viewGroup also to try the same treatment,

There will be a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up to use `ExpanderableListView` to check the amount of change in the y-axis when it is scrolled.

Use `recyclerView` with `OnScrollListener` instead of `expanderableListView'.